# Escaping and sanitization

Tags: plugins, sanitization, escaping

I have created a custom metabox for a certain plugin - events CPT. In it I can add talks by event days, with images, speaker names, descriptions, titles and times. So all either input fields or textareas that I pick up on post save, in the `$_POST` variable, are put in the array, and saved in the post meta.

Now on post save I have standard

```
    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ){
        return;
    }

    if ( !current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id) ){
        return;
    }

    if ( !isset( $_POST['talk_fields_meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['talk_fields_meta_box_nonce'], 'talk_field_nonce' ) ){
        return;
    }
```

and then I set my array in which I add the inputs look like

```
$talk_title = $_POST['talk_title_'.$i];
$new_events[$i][$j]['talk_title'] = stripslashes( strip_tags( $talk_title ) );
```

for instance (I'm looping here, that's why I have `$i` and `$j`). This array is then added to a post meta, and when I look at it in my database, the value is saved as serialized array.

When I pull that info out to fill the metabox I am using either `esc_attr()`, `esc_html()` or `wp_kses_post()` (for description in the textarea) as a sanitization.

What I am wondering is if I'm safe from any kind of attacks by not using [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)?

I mean, on save I'm checking if a user can edit the post, I have nonce check, and I'm escaping on output. Can my database be corrupted in any way - pasting something in a textarea and saving the post for instance? Or am I safe?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you're doing fine - but I would suggest using WP's [`sanitize_text_field`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_text_field) for sanitizing non-textarea form inputs. It'll handle things like line breaks, invalid UTF-8, whitespace, octets etc.

Comment: So on my input fields where I have title of the talk, name of the talkers etc. I should just use `sanitize_text_field`? Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `stripslashes( strip_tags( $talk_title ) )` use `sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $talk_title ) )`

Comment: Great, seems to be working without a problem :) Thanks!